# Does wifi range depends on the receiver

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am making a device that with a camera that has to send live video streaming to a remote. The problem is that I need long range transmission in open space (no walls) so I decided that the device will be placed on high ground and will have a router connected to it, but I don't know if the remote will need a high power router too, to communicate on long distances with the device or if a low power receiver will be enough.

My question is If the router on the device has high power, does the router (or wifi module) on the remote need high power too?

Router specification:

- Power: 28 dBm
- Sensitivity -75 -90 dB
- Antenna gain 5-10 dB (Not sure yet which one to choose)

Comment: Depends on what 'long range' means.  It takes both the transmitter and a receiver to get the signal. If the signal is strong the receiver may be less than optimal. The further away you are the weaker the signal.

Comment: Keep in mind that both devices are sending during a communication.

Comment: What do you mean by "less than optimal" and by long range I mean 1 or 2 km